# How do I compute the barycenter of an histogram represented as polar coordinate

Tags: python, polar-coordinates

I display a histogram as a polar plot and I want to display the barycenter to see if there is a dominant orientation of the histogram.
My issue is when the histogram have a lot of 0 and 2pi value, the barycenter is not working (because 0 and 2pi is the same angle in the polar plot)

So I get something like this :
[image]

I expect to see the red dot at 0 degree.

Here's a minimal example code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.rand(1000)*3.14*2
a = np.hstack((a,np.ones(100)*0.1))
a = np.hstack((a,np.ones(100)*3.1*2))
f = plt.figure()
f.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='polar')
n, bins = np.histogram(np.array(a), 50)
n = n / np.sum(n)
plt.hist((bins[0:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2, weights=n, bins=bins, rwidth=1.)
binscenter = (bins[0:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
moyenne = np.sum(n * binscenter) / np.sum(n)
plt.scatter(moyenne ,0.1,c='r')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is **circular statistics**.

We usually work with data that has a linear support, i.e. the data can be represented over the real line. But quantities like angles do not have a linear rather a circular support, so we need specialized theory to deal with them.

Luckily, [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.circmean.html) already has a few functions to compute descriptive statistics for circular data. Here is an example:

```py
import math

import numpy as np
import scipy

data = [0.0, 0.0, 2 * math.pi, 2 * math.pi]

linear_mean = np.mean(data)
circular_mean = scipy.stats.circmean(data)
```

As you can see, `linear_mean` returns `pi`, while `circular_mean` returns `2pi`.

If you want to know more about circular statistics, I deeply suggest to read this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199671133).